# How can I keep the page from refreshing after using window.location.replace

Tags: javascript

The follwing javascript code is doing what it's intended to do, which is to replace the URL but then the page won't stop reloading/refreshing. Is there a way to stop it?

Original page is: *`www.xyz.com/used-vehicles`*, but I want to automatically use the checkbox filter options on that page which adds to the URL after used-vehicles `?search=certified%2Cpreowned`

```
<script>
document.location.replace('/used-vehicles?search=certified%2Cpreowned');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Put this under condition to match if URL already contains the replaced string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your url already doesn't contain `search=certified%2Cpreowned`:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("search=certified%2Cpreowned") == -1){
   window.location.replace('/used-vehicles?search=certified%2Cpreowned');
}
```

Comment: Follow up question: This method wouldn't create two sessions in google analytics, would it?

Comment: Most likely wouldn't create two sessions, but it might create two page hits though. I couldn't find anything conclusive and light enough that I could point you to, so I would test it myself to be a 100% sure.